# Multiple actions were found that match the request - WebApi

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I have added WebApi to an existing MVC app and create a controller with a post method.   I have one route configured in the webapiconfig.  When I use Fiddler to post to the controller, I am receiving the "Multiple Actions" error.  my ApiConfig and Controller are posted below.   There is some Ioc and DI going on with Ninject.   Do I need to add different routes definitions, or is this about the data being posted?

webapiconfig.cs

```
 public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {

        var jsonFormatter = config.Formatters.OfType<JsonMediaTypeFormatter>().First();
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "Materials",
        routeTemplate: "api/materials/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "materials", id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

MaterialController.

```
using ????.Info.DAL;
using ????.Info.Models;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;
using IdentitySample.Models;

namespace ????.Info.Controllers.Api
{
public class MaterialsController : BaseApiController
{
    public MaterialsController(I????Repository repo)
        :base(repo)
    {
    }
    [Route("api/materials/")]
    public IEnumerable<MaterialModel> Get()
    {

        IQueryable<MaterialEntities.Materials> query;

        query = TheRepository.GetAllMaterials();

        var results = query
            .ToList()
            .Select(s => TheModelFactory.Create(s));

        return results;

    }
     [Route("api/materials/{id:int}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetMaterial(int id)
    {

        try
        {
            var material = TheRepository.GetMaterial(id);
            if (material != null)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, TheModelFactory.Create(material));
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
            }

        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }

    }

    [HttpPost]

    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] MaterialModel materialModel)
    {
        try
        {
            var entity = TheModelFactory.Parse(materialModel);

            if (entity == null) Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not read MaterialType/Organization from body");

            if (TheRepository.Insert(entity) && TheRepository.SaveAll())
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created, TheModelFactory.Create(entity));
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, "Could not save to the database.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, ex);
        }
    }


    public MaterialEntities.Materials Parse(MaterialModel materialmodel)
     { 
         try 
         { 
             var material = new MaterialEntities.Materials()
                { 
                    Name = materialmodel.Name,
                    Description = materialmodel.Description, 
                    DateCreated = materialmodel.DateCreated,   

                };


             return material; 
         } 
         catch (Exception) 
         { 

             return null; 
         } 
     } 


}
```

}

Comment: 1.Do you have any other actions in the controller? 2. Why don't use use AttributeRouting? 3. Try adding [HttpPost] above the action.

Comment: There are other actions.  2.  I haven't dove into AttributeRouting yet.   3.  I will try that first.

Comment: No luck.  I added the HttpPost and tried AttributeRouting.  Here is the entire controller.

Comment: I am not using Attribute Routing but should not you remove the route definition in the WebApi config class?

Comment: Try to replace your existing WebApiConfig code with the following: configuration.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

            configuration.Routes.MapHttpRoute("API Default", "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { id = RouteParameter.Optional });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks for all the help on this.  This was fixed by adding `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();`  to the WebApiConfig.   I removed the default route definitions since I am going to use AttributeRouting and it's working now.

update:  It looks like it is possible to mix Attribute and Convention routing in the WebApiConfig as discussed [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2)  So my problem was solved by adding `config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();` to WebApiConfig